# The metric for Google Sheets. "Per user" - what is it? It's for service accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

The metric for Google Sheets. `"Per minute per user"` - what is it?

It's for service accounts?

Comment: [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits)

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of quotas. Project based quotas which effect your project as a whole and all its users.  There is also user based quotas which effect each user who is accessing the api.

User based quotas are there to prevent flooding of the api endpoint by a single user

Yes service accounts are also limited by the per user quota.  So it will also get throttled if you send to many requests at once.